# What does .where.get() return?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

i am new this website and to mobile programming.

My questions is:

In firebase i have a collection path with some documents.
`.collection(maybe).doc(random)`

Each doc has subcollection as well.
Also each doc has data such as:

```
roomName: randomName
roomPassword: randomPass.
```

So, now i would like to use the query with `.where` operator and `.get` like this:

```
const docRef=db.collection(‘maybe’)
docRef.where(‘roomName’ ‘==‘ ‘randomName’).get()
```

My question is what do i get back? As i understand i get the querySnapshot, but i do not fully get how to get the second field in data specifically i.e. how to get roomPass?

Comment: You get back a [promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise): https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Query#get . The documentation provides examples for how to access the data: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const docRef = db.collection(‘maybe’); 
const futureSnapshot = docRef.where(‘roomName’,‘==‘,‘randomName’).get();
```

gives you a promise of snapshot.

You have to "await".

```
const docRef = db.collection(‘maybe’); 
const snapshot = await docRef.where(‘roomName’,‘==‘,‘randomName’).get();
```

after that you can get your data :

```
const room = snapshot.data(); // undefined if your query has no results
```

[This link could help you](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_a_document)

Happy coding !

**EDIT**
If your document looks like this :

```
{
  randomName: "a name",
  randomPassword: "a password"
}
```

Then you get your data like that :

```
const room = snapshot.data(); // undefined if your query has no results
const { randomPassword } = room;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer sir. I have read trough documentation have useD .get before. However i just dont know how Do get specific line from data. What i am trying to say is how should i use doc.data() to get only roomPassword line not the whole doc.data? Could i specify which line i would like to get from the doc??

Comment: your are welcome. If you console.log "room", you'll see that it's just a regular javascript object. Just do room.roomPassword ?